# Django- IndentationError

Tags: django

Hello everyone I am new to django please help me to solve error,I am using termux for it and Acoder for editing code
**In my django urls.py code**
[In urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvxsn.png)

In termux error showing like this
[Error message of indentation in urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuQSc.png)

Comment: Can i see your myapp.urls?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a comma at the end of the 2nd path specification in urls.py

It is usual to have a comma after every line under these circumstances, even the last one.

Without knowing more about your code, it is hard to say, but I would try that one first.